# Has it any solution ,$ \frac{1}{n^{0.01}} - \frac{1}{ln(n)} =0 $ For $ n > 0 ,real$?

Tags: real-analysis, convergence-divergence

What is the solution of the following equation?

$ \frac{1}{n^{0.01}} - \frac{1}{ln(n)} =0 $ For $ n > 0 ,real$

**1.** I was checking convergence of the following series.$$ \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{n^{0.01}}. \frac{1}{n}       .......(1)$$ And  $$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{ln(n)}. \frac{1}{n}   .......(2)$$

$1st$ one is convergent $2nd$ one is divergent (from integral test).

**2.** I can see from L'Hospital rule that$ Lim_{n\to \infty } \frac{n^{0.01}}{ln(n)}$ blows up  ,supporting the fact that  $\frac{1}{n^{0.01}} < \frac{1}{ln(n)}$ for higher values of $  n  $

**3.** Ok. Now from plotting graphs of $ \frac{1}{n^{0.01}} and \frac{1}{ln(n)} $ ,
I obsereve that upto the domain , computer can provide , it is always like this ,  $\frac{1}{n^{0.01}} >\frac{1}{ln(n)}$

Therefore I conclude there must be some value of n , where they are equal . What is that point ? I cannot find it numerically .

Answer (score 1):

$\frac{1}{n^{0.01}} - \frac{1}{\ln(n)} = 0$ implies $\frac{1}{n^{0.01}} = \frac{1}{\ln(n)}$, so $n^{0.01} = \ln(n)$. 
 Numerically, it turns out to have two solutions: $n\approx 2.746$ and $n\approx 1.285 \cdot 10^{281}$. See [Wolfram|Alpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=n%5E0.01+%3D+ln(n)).

This can not be expressed in elementary functions, but needs the Lambert W function.

Let $n^{-0.01} = k$, then $n=k^{-100}$. So $\frac{1}{k} = \ln(k^{-100})$. So $-100 k \ln(k) =1$, and $k \ln(k) = -\frac{1}{100}$, so $e^{\ln(k)} \ln(k) = -\frac{1}{100}$, so $\ln(k) = W_{0}(-\frac{1}{100})$ or $\ln(k) = W_{-1}(-\frac{1}{100})$.

This gives $k = e^{W_{0}(-\frac{1}{100})}$ or $k = e^{W_{-1}(-\frac{1}{100})}$. Hence $n =  e^{-100 W_{0}(-\frac{1}{100})}$ or $k = e^{-100 W_{-1}(-\frac{1}{100})}$